# Chart won't update when data changes ng2-charts

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using `ng2-charts` render a simple pie chart in my component like so:

```
<canvas baseChart [data]="chartData" [colors]="chartColors" [options]="{ tooltips: { enabled: false } }"
  chartType="pie"></canvas>
```

In my component class I have this chart directive which is supposed to be populated with chart object. But if I call `this.chart.update()` after assigning new value to `chartData` I get an undefined error.

```
export class TransactionDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(BaseChartDirective) chart: BaseChartDirective;
  chartData: number[] = [];
  generateChartData() {
    //make an api call
    this.chartData = [ //new data ];
}
```

Calling the `generateChartData()` method works fine the first time but chart does not get updated on subsequent calls. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't see the problem with your code, please add demo. https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-pie-template-uxpp6h?file=src/app/app.module.ts , example to demonstrate your problem

Comment: Its working fine the link you posted